# Discord bot using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Right now I'm making a Discord Bot written in Python. I'm using SQLAlchemy to deal with the database.

My structure is:

- One `database.py` containing a `DatabaseConnection` class initializing the SQLAlchemy engine, and making a new session with the DB every time i use it
- Many `.py` file(each file for different purposes) containing a class inheriting `DatabaseConnection`

Example:

`database.py`:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, Session

class DatabaseConnection:
    def __init__(self):
        self.engine = create_engine(DB_URI, echo=False)
        self.session = None

    def __enter__(self) -> Session:
        self.session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)()
        return self.session

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.session.close()
```

`example.py`:

```py
from database import DatabaseConnection

class Foo(DatabaseConnection):
    def get_bar(self):
        with self as session:
            #do thing
```

My question is, is this a right way to use inheritance? Or is it just better calling directly to `DatabaseConnection`? Can it cause problems? Are there better/cleaner/more pythonic ways to do it?

Comment: @Reinderien it is, if you mean the unclosed/passed `with` statement, or the undeclared "DB_URI" variable, i'm aware of them, despite that, the code works like it should. Still, i will try to post more code

Comment: Fixed ; thank you!